# Global variables not changing as expected from methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs, module, global-variables

**I am using this module in a react program that a component imports this module. I am needing the access token once received to be stored in the global variable but for some reason that I cant figure out it seems the global variables are not changing as desired**

```
let usersAccessToken = '';
const clientId = 'ca47d370807d46718c513653fb3d2e';
const UriRedirect = 'http://localhost:3000/';
let flag = false;
console.log(flag);
console.log(usersAccessToken);



const Spotify = {



    getAccessToken: function () {
        //
        if (usersAccessToken.length>0) {
            console.log('step 1');
            flag = true;

            return usersAccessToken;


        } else if (window.location.href.match(/access_token=([^&]*)/) !== null && window.location.href.match(/expires_in=([^&]*)/) !== null) {
```

**At this point in the code Im wondering why userAccessToken is not stored in the global variable above the module? I know the value is being stored locally but I need that value to be changed globally. when I console.log it it always remains an empty string and also my boolean flags are not changing?

```
console.log('step 2');
            usersAccessToken = window.location.href.match(/access_token=([^&]*)/)[1];

            let expirationTime = window.location.href.match(/expires_in=([^&]*)/)[1];

            window.setTimeout(() => usersAccessToken = '', expirationTime );
            window.history.pushState('Access Token', null, '/');
            flag = true;

            return usersAccessToken;

        } else {
            console.log('step 3');
            flag = true;

            window.location = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=${clientId}&response_type=token&scope=playlist-modify-public&redirect_uri=${UriRedirect}`;

        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This below code is working fine,You can have a look to the below code this works good to me.

Tested at...
https://repl.it/repls/PitifulEarlyMapping

```
let usersAccessToken = '';
let flag = false;
console.log(flag);
console.log('token',usersAccessToken);
getAccessToken();

function getAccessToken() {
    if (usersAccessToken.length>0) {
        console.log('step 1');
        flag = true;
        return usersAccessToken;
    } else if (flag== false) {
      console.log('step 2');
        usersAccessToken = 'tokebjzgdhjasgfj';
        return usersAccessToken;
    } else {
        console.log('step 3');
        flag = true;
        return usersAccessToken;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is not changing the global variable if I test the values of the global variables they remain in their original state.

Comment: Have you checked the link i mentioned above.